# How to solve this non-linear differential equation of 2nd order?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am looking for ideas to help me solve this equation:
$$y''=y^5+y^2y' $$
I thought of multiplying this equation by $y'$ then integrate, but it does not seem to work.

I thought of switching the variable $y=\frac{1}{u}$ but it got worse.

Any idea would be helpfull, thank you in advance.

Comment: why do you think a closed form exists?

Comment: i don't really know, my math teacher told me to solve it.

Comment: Please provide the exact task statement. What is understood as a solution, are there initial values,...

Comment: The question is exactly states as follows:
"Solve:
$y''=y^5+y^2y'$. "

Answer (score 1):

There's a standard trick for when independent variable doesn't appear in the second-order equation.  Let $z = dy/dx$.  Then $y'' = dz/dx = (dz/dy)(dy/dx) = (dz/dy) z.$  Plug these into your equation, and $y$ becomes the new independent variable in a first order equation:

$$\frac{dz}{dy}z = y^5+y^2z.$$

If you can solve this equation for $z = \mbox{ crud },$ then you write $y' = \mbox{ crud }$ and try to solve that.  (But how to solve that first equation is beyond me.  Maple gives a very ugly, implicit answer.)